# Method of constant coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I saw this question: $y''+y=\cot x$

As supposed I solved the homogenous part by forming the characteristic equations: $r^2 + 1 =0$. and obtained the solution for the homogenous part as : $$y = C_1\cos x + C_2\sin x.$$ But I am a bit confused as to solve the non homogenous part using the method of constant coefficient. Can anyone assist ?

Comment: Yes I have learned variation of parameters, but just wanted to know if the equation can be solved by constant coefficient

Comment: Ok. Supposing I am to use method of constant coefficients in the computation of the non homogenous, what will be the guess of cotx, will it be sinx + cos x?

Comment: No, the method of undetermined coefficients does not work here, as it only works if all terms on the right are of the polynomial times exponential type. The trig functions sine and cosine are sums and differences of complex exponentials, so they count. The (co-)tangent can not be written that way.

Comment: I think this is not what the method is called. Do you mean undetermined coefficients as LutzL says?

Comment: @LutzL, technically the method still works, doesn't it? The integral could be non-elementary, but that's a whole other business. In this case, it is a rational combination of trig functions, so also elementary

Comment: @YuriyS : Undetermined coefficients is the "guessing" method, no integrals involved. Variation of constants leads to the integral $\int\frac{\cos^2 x}{\sin x}\,dx$ which can be solved with the method for rational trig. functions, but has no "easy" anti-derivative in trig. terms.

Comment: @LutzL, I see. Stumped again by English language

Comment: I had similar view that it can't be solved by the method of undetermined coefficient because one can not get a guess of cotx when solving the non homogenous part